# Sketch the region in the plane consisting of all points (x,y) such that $2xy\le |x-y|\le x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

**Question**: Sketch the region in the plane consisting of all points (x,y) such that $2xy\le |x-y|\le x^2+y^2$

**My attempt**:
If $x>y$ then
$|x-y|=x-y$
Thus now,
$2xy\le x-y\le x^2+y^2$
If $x-y\geq 2xy$ then let $x-y=k$ ($k$ is some real number)
then $y=x-k \tag{1}$ 
Thus the straight line (1) has a negative slope. 
After this how to proceed?

Comment: Thanks Henrik for editing. I am really poor at Latex. Please do not mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2xy\le |x-y|\le x^2+y^2$$

First, consider the inequality on the right.

Depending on whether $x$ or $y$ is the larger of the two the second inequality resolves into the two inequalities

$$ \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\ge\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 $$

or

$$ \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\ge\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 $$

So the solution set must lie outside the interiors of these two circles.

The first inequality resolves into the two inequalities

$$ 2xy\le x-y \text{ given that } x\ge y$$

$$ 2xy\le y-x\text{ given that } x\le y $$

The first inequality can be re-written as

\begin{eqnarray}
2xy-x+y &\le& 0\\
xy-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y-\frac{1}{4} &\le& -\frac{1}{4}\\
\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right) &\le& -\frac{1}{4} \text{ and }y\le x
\end{eqnarray}
The graph of this inequality consists of all points lying on or below the right branch of the hyperbola.

Similiarly, the second inequality can be re-formed as

$$ \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right) \le -\frac{1}{4} \text{ and }y\ge x$$

The graph of this inequality consists of all points lying on or above the left branch of this hyperbola.

The darker region in the following is the solution set.

[image: Solution set of inequality.]

Answer (score 0):

we have $$2xy\le |x-y|\le x^2+y^2$$ now we assume $$x\geq y$$ then we get
$$2xy\le x-y$$ and $$x-y\le x^2+y^2$$
the right inequality Can be written as $$\frac{1}{2}\le (x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y-\frac{1}{2})^2$$
the left Hand side is:
$$y(1+2x)\le x$$ 
$$x=-\frac{1}{2}$$ gives a contradiction
if $$x<-\frac{1}{2}$$ we get $$y\geq \frac{x}{1+2x}$$
if $$x>-\frac{1}{2}$$ we get $$y\le \frac{x}{1+2x}$$
Can you finish now?

Comment: y<=x/(1+2x) gives me what type of curve? I mean I understand that 1/2≤(x−1/2)^2+(y−1/2)^2 gives me all circles whose centers are (1/2,1/2)  and radii greater than or equaal to 1/2but y(1+2x)<=x can be drawn in which way?

Comment: can you use a calculator? in the other case use a table of Points, or Wolfram Alpha

Comment: But still the plot of y<=x/(1+2x) & 1/2≤(x−1/2)^2+(y−1/2)^2 does not make sense at all. I mean what will be the sketch of the plot like? I failed to reckon that. Sorry.

Comment: you must also consider the other case $$x<-\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$y\geq \frac{x}{1+2x}$$